# what is similar to layout_weight in relativelyout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout, android-linearlayout

In `LinearLayout` we can populate elements horizontally by using Layout_Weight which makes them occupy all the width and the width each take depends on their Layout_Weight value(or ratio). My question is how can I do the same in case of `RelativeLayout`. There is no attribute like Layout_Weight.
I am using a `RelativeLayout` in my project and it contains 4 buttons which need to be at the bottom of the screen and must fill the whole width. If I use hardcode `Layout_Width="20dp"` or something like that. It created a problem when I change the orientation from Portrait to Landscape or vice versa.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/feed_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:text="@string/feed"
            android:textColor="#FF000000" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/iwant_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/feed_button"
            android:text="@string/iwant"
            android:textColor="#FF000000" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/share_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/iwant_button"
            android:text="@string/share"
            android:textColor="#FF000000" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/profile_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/share_button"
            android:text="@string/profile"
            android:textColor="#FF000000" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in relative layout we can achieve this dynamically.

```
DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);

int height = metrics.heightPixels;
int width = metrics.widthPixels;

Button1.setWidth(width / 2);
Button2.setWidth(width / 2);
```

Answer (score 0):

for making relative layout to take full width

```
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
```

to add it at the bottom

```
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
```

Comment: if i use fill parent for every button only the last button will be visible....rest all will get overlapped

Comment: see there is nothing in relative layout as weight you can make them wrap_content or you create them on run time calculate each button width as parentwidth/4 then assign to buttons still there you have to mess up with the positioning of buttons

Comment: Archie.bpgc why dont you add your four button in linear layout and then add it to your relative layout

Answer (score 0):

I think that there is no attribute like `layout_weight` in `Relative layout` .
But android has given functionality with `Linear Layout` . In that case, why would you want to go with `Relative layout`?

I think you know how to use `layout_weight` in `Linear Layout`.

```
<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/feed_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:text="feed"
        android:textColor="#FF000000" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/iwant_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:text="iwant"
        android:textColor="#FF000000" />


</LinearLayout>
```

I know you have compulsory use Relative Layout But if you put above code in your activity it show all buttons at bottom of display and If want to show those button layout at below of any other layout then use `android:layout_below attributte` in `<LinearLayout >` tag and use outer most layout as Relative Layout

Thanks

Comment: yeah...but the problem is my project needs relative layout for many reasons....for this single reason i cannot switch to linear layout

Comment: hi :D u wrking on some android project @ ps?

Comment: @Archie.bpgc can share your layout file I will tell you exact solution on it

Comment: actual this is a part of my project...what i want to tell is...RelativeLayout is compulsory.

Comment: I dont want your whole code you can give code which you have use at bottom only

Comment: yeah its pasted in the question

Answer (score 0):

The only way to ensure the buttons are all equal with would be to put them in a `LinearLayout` that fills the area you want the buttons to cover like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

   <LinearLayout
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
      android:orientation="vertical" >
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/feed_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:text="@string/feed"
            android:textColor="#FF000000" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/iwant_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/feed_button"
            android:text="@string/iwant"
            android:textColor="#FF000000" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/share_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:text="@string/share"
            android:textColor="#FF000000" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/profile_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:text="@string/profile"
            android:textColor="#FF000000" />
  </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

The `LinearLayout` will fill the entire width of the parent layout and will divide the buttons evenly based on their weight.

There is a very nifty trick if you have two layouts that you want to divide evenly in `RelativeLayout`.  Create an "invisible" layout of 0x0 pixels, align it to the center of the parent view, then align the two layouts to the invisible layout relative to where you want them.